# i want to show the update form in different page means different view how to do in ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller update.php

```
 <?php
         class Update extends CI_Controller{

        function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('update_model');
          }



function show_subcategory_id()
{
 $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
 $data['subcategory'] = $this->update_model->show_subcategory();
 $data['category']=$this->update_model->show_category();
 $data['single_subcategory'] = $this->update_model-

   >show_subcategory_id($id);
  $this->load->view('admin/esub', $data);
       }


       function update_subcategory_id1() {
       $id= $this->input->post('did');
         $data = array(
       'namesubcategory' => $this->input->post('dname'),
        'urlsubcategory' => $this->input->post('durl'),
        'idcategory' => $this->input->post('parent_menu'),
                );
   $this->update_model->update_subcategory_id1($id,$data);
   $this->show_subcategory_id();
   }

    }
      ?>
```

this is model update_model.php

```
     <?php

       class Update_model extends CI_Model{

      function show_category(){
       $query = $this->db->get('category');
       $query_result = $query->result();
         return $query_result;
         }

           function show_subcategory(){
            $query = $this->db->get('subcategory');
             $query_result = $query->result();
             return $query_result;
                   }

               function show_subcategory_id($data){
              $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('subcategory');
               $this->db->where('idsubcategory', $data);
                $query = $this->db->get();
               $result = $query->result();
              return $result;  
                 }

        function update_subcategory_id1($id,$data){
          $this->db->where('idsubcategory', $id);
             $this->db->update('subcategory', $data);  
                 }

                 }

                 ?>
```

This is view update_view.php

```
                        <ol>
                    <?php foreach ($subcategory as $student): ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() . 
           "admin/update/show_subcategory_id/" . $student->idsubcategory; ?
             >"><?php echo $student->namesubcategory; ?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>

                 <?php foreach ($single_subcategory as $student): ?>
                    <p>Edit Detail & Click Update Button</p>

                    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() .
                    "admin/update/update_subcategory_id1"?>">
                        <label id="hide">Id :</label><br/> 
                        <input type="text" id="hide" name="did" value="<?php
                      echo $student->idsubcategory; ?>"><br/>      

                        <label>Name :</label><br/> 
                        <input type="text" name="dname" value="<?php echo
                          $student->namesubcategory; ?>"><br/>    

                        <label>url :</label><br/> 
                        <input type="text" name="durl" value="<?php echo
                           $student->urlsubcategory; ?>"><br/>

                         <label>Parent Menu :</label><br/> 
                        <select name="parent_menu">
                         <?php foreach ($category as $s):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $s->idcategory;?>">
                        <?php echo $s->namecategory; ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="dsubmit" 
                          value="Update">
                    </form>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is working fine but i want show the subcategory name results and the update form in different view page ...Is it possible..??how to do that?

Comment: please answer to this question ....thnx

Comment: In which view do you want to show it?

Comment: In your controller, inject the data which you get from your model in the view you want and then display it in your view.

Comment: actually i want to shoew the update form by clicking the name of subcategory in different page where the list of category names are not shown

Comment: please answer in code i cant understand what u tell

Comment: I don't see enough code to provide the code specific to your project. Please provide... Which controller, controller method, model method and view get called for the current page to work? And which ones would you call for your other page?

Comment: i done this process ahead so i give my code. have any confusion free to ask

Comment: i am quite confuse about your question ... is you get a value on that update page  check it threw "var_dump".

Answer (score 1):

```
                <select name="city_id">

            <?php

            foreach ($records_city as $row) { 

            if(isset($arrSelectCity[$row->city_id])) {

            ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row->city_id; ?>" selected="selected" ><?php echo $row->city_name; ?></option><?php 
            }
            else{

            ?><option value="<?php echo $row->city_id; ?>" > <?php echo $row->city_name; ?></option>

            <?php
            }   
            }
            ?></select>


            HEAR what i understand what u want is u have to show sub category name than foreach all
            the data of that category and then done it as i show you as above code that i got city 
            name.
```

replay my comment if you have any query????